# unable to cast String to a doubly linked list node

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, queue, nodes

Im having an exception error with regards to casting a String to one of my methods. I was using [Singly linked list node not able to be cast as Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476547/singly-linked-list-node-not-able-to-be-cast-as-integer) as a reference but I can't seem to figure out the problem. My main method is provided by prof and i have to run it and test my methods.  The error is happening with `String s = test.dequeue();`

```
public static void testQueue() {
        System.out.println("Test queues");
        Queue<String> test = new Queue<String>();
        test.enqueue("a");
        test.enqueue("b");
        System.out.println(test);
        test.enqueue("c");
        test.enqueue("d");
        test.enqueue("e");
        test.enqueue("f");
        System.out.println(test);
        String s = test.dequeue();
        System.out.println("dequeued " + s + ": " + test);
        test.enqueue("x");
        test.enqueue("y");
        test.enqueue("z");
        System.out.println(test);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                s = test.dequeue();
                System.out.println("dequeued " + s + ": " + test);
            }
        }
        catch(QueueException ex) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + ex);
        }
        test.enqueue("j");
        test.enqueue("k");
        test.enqueue("l");
        System.out.println("Final value: " + test);
    }

    // Test Stacks
    public static void testStack() {

        System.out.println("Test stacks");
        Stack<String> test = new Stack<String>();
        test.push("a");
        test.push("b");
        System.out.println(test);
        test.push("c");
        test.push("d");
        test.push("e");
        test.push("f");
        System.out.println(test);
        String s = test.pop();
        System.out.println("popped " + s + ": " + test);
        test.push("x");
        test.push("y");
        test.push("z");
        System.out.println(test);
        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                s = test.pop();
                System.out.println("popped " + s + ": " + test);
            }
        }
        catch(StackException ex) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + ex);
        }
        test.push("j");
        test.push("k");
        test.push("l");
        System.out.println("Final value: " + test);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        testQueue();
        testStack();
    }
```

The queue method is also below. Im using my LinkedList method to call my functions.

```
public class Queue<T> implements QueueInterface<T> {
    LinkedList list;
    public Queue(){ //constructor
        list = new LinkedList();
    }

    public void enqueue(T data) { //add to the bottom of queue
        list.add(data, list.size);
    }


    public T dequeue() { //remove from top of queue
        Object result = (list.get(0));
        list.remove(0);
        return (T)result;
    }


    public int size() { //get the size of queue
        list.size();
        return 0;
    }


    public T peek() { //get the data on the top of queue
        list.get(0);
        return null;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return list.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line is the error?

Comment: @Pritam Banerjee sorry i know its hard to find, its within `testQueue()` at `String s = test.dequeue();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dequeue() method, you are returning an Object type but instead you should be returning a 'T' type. You can modify your code to the below.

```
public T dequeue() { //remove from top of queue
    return list.get(0);
}
```

or you can also typecast Object to T, in this case String

```
 public T dequeue() { //remove from top of queue
        Object result = (list.get(0));
        list.remove(0);
        return (T)result;
    }
```

Comment: for some reason i removed the typecast, but I already tried that method and it didnt work. Is there a way to keep my object?

Comment: `public T dequeue() { //remove from top of queue

        list.remove(0);

        return (T) list.get(0);

    }`

my ide says I have to typecast it, but regardless it still isnt working?

Comment: @Jordles you need to explicitly say what you mean by "not working".  Is the result not what you expected?  Is it throwing an exception?  If so, what exception?  (At a guess, you `remove(0)` the item before you do `get(0)`, so `get()` isn't going to return the correct item and will return `null` if there was only one item - likely causing a NullPointerException)

Comment: @Jordles correction, it'll throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Tibrogargan ok so the problem was with my LinkedList, cause my get method was returning the Node and not the value of the node(cause im dum) . Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
String s = (String) test.dequeue();
```

In your example it was `String` so you we casted a `String`, but suppose it is an `Integer` you can use:

```
Integer i = (Integer) test.dequeue();
```

But it is better to do it the way @justnisar pointed out.

Comment: so it did nothing. My IDE is saying casting it to String is redundant